# Set of all homomorphisms of G into the group of nonzero complex numbers under multiplication is Abelian

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

I am having trouble with the following problem, taken from Herstein's *Topics in Algebra* 2nd Edition:

> If $G$ is an abelian group, let $\hat G$ be the set of all homomorphisms of $G$
> into the group of nonzero complex numbers under multiplication.
> If, $\phi_1,\phi_2\in \hat G$, define $\phi_1 \cdot \phi_2$ by $\phi_1 \cdot \phi_2(g) = \phi_1(g) \phi_2 (g)$ for all $g \in G.$
>
> Show that $\hat G$ is an abelian group under the operation defined

I tried to take advantage of the fact that since $G$ is abelian, we must have, $\forall g_1,g_2 \in G$

$\phi_1 \cdot \phi_2(g_1g_2) = \phi_1(g_1g_2) \phi_2 (g_1g_2)=\phi_1(g_2g_1) \phi_2 (g_2g_1)=\phi_1 \cdot \phi_2(g_2g_1)$,

but this has not gotten me any closer to showing that,

$\phi_1 \cdot \phi_2(g_1g_2)=\phi_2 \cdot \phi_1(g_1g_2)$.

Is this the wrong direction to proceed from? This comes from the section that introduces the Fundamental Theorem of Finite Abelian Groups, but I don't see how I can leverage that for this problem.

Comment: It's trivial that $\phi_1\cdot \phi_2=\phi_2\cdot\phi_1$ because multiplication of complex numbers is commutative. You're simply multiplying the functions pointwise.

Comment: @MattSamuel Thanks a lot, I guess I was just over thinking it.

Comment: @user389773 You probably got thrown by the requirement that $G$ be Abelian. The statement is true for any arbitrary group $G$ and homomorphisms from it into any Abelian group $H$.  In fact, it's true for any *function* into an Abelian group. It's actually not hard, given a formal definition of "algebraic", to prove that this is true about any algebraic structure, e.g. functions into rings are rings.